# In a Poisson process measured with some efficiency, is the measured count still Poisson?

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution

**Situation:**

Say I have a Poisson process, like radioactive decay, producing *R* particles per second. I measure with a detector. There is a probability *P* that a particle will be detected by the detector.

**Things I think I know:**

1. The inter-arrival time of the particle emission is exponentially
   distributed with parameters based on *R*.
2. The number of particles emitted before detection is given by a
   negative binomial based on *P*.
3. If a number *N* is sampled from (2), a single sample of inter-arrival time for detected particles can be given by the sum of *N* samples from (1). This sum can be obtained by sampling from a gamma distribution with parameters based on *N* and *R*.

**My question:**

If a single inter-arrival time can be calculated by sampling from a gamma based on *N* and *R*, how does the number of detector counts in an interval end up being Poisson again? (To be Poisson, the inter-arrival time for the detector must be exponential, not distributed according to some weird gamma thing.) Of course *N* is fluctuating, but I can't see how this works out.

However, I am almost completely sure detector counts are in fact Poisson distributed. Could somebody show me the math?
Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

I found this paper:
Fried, D. L. "Noise in photoemission current." Applied Optics 4.1 (1965): 79-80.

Which shows the result that a binomially selected poisson random variable is also Poisson with a rate given by PR. This confirms the comment by jbowman. Still, I would be interested in seeing the explanation of how my process of generating the inter-arrival time at the detector using the negative binomial and gamma distribution is incorrect. This is my major mental hiccup. Thank you.

EDIT 2:

I wrote this matlab script to test whether what I was trying with the gamma distribution worked. Turns out that somehow the gamma inter-arrival times generated with a geometrically distributed N are exponential and agree with the inter-arrival times suggested by Poisson(PR). (ia2 and ia3 are identically distributed). Any idea how this works out analytically? It was not intuitively obvious to me!

```
close all
n = 100000;
ia1 = exprnd(1,n,1); % create exponentially distributed inter-arrival times
t1 = cumsum(ia1); % running sum (the real experiment time)

mask = (rand(n,1) > 0.5); % flip a coin
t2 = t1(mask); % get only the events for which "the coin landed on heads"
ia2 = diff(t2); % calculate the inter-arrival times at the detector.

% plot the distributions
figure; hist(ia1,100); title('exponential inter-arrival times');
figure; hist(ia2,100); title('binomial sampled inter-arrival times');

%%
spacing = geornd(0.5,n,1) + 1; % how many events before we get heads
ia3 = gamrnd(spacing,ones(n,1)); % generate the interarrival times with gamma
figure; hist(ia3,100); title('geom/gamma inter-arrival times');
```

Comment: #2 is actually not correct; if each particle has a probability $P$ of being detected, the distribution of detected particles per second is Poisson($RP$) (assuming detections are independent etc.)  For #3, if $N$ is sampled from 2, then you don't have a single sample of inter-arrival times; you have a single observation of the sum of $N$ interarrival times, which is indeed distributed Gamma with shape parameter $N$.  Consequently, the premise of your question ("If a single interarrival time...") isn't true.

Comment: I don't understand how you know the rate is Poisson(RP). Could you show me? That is the very heart of this question I think. In #2, I suppose that I have if I have a P chance to hit the detector, the number of particles emitted before hitting the detector is Geometrically distributed with a mean of 1/P. Thus, I can calculate can sample from this Geometric distribution to get N, then sum up N inter-arrival times to get a single inter-arrival time at the detector. Can you explain the flaw in this logic? I think your statement about the rate being Poisson(RP) is important. Thank you!

Comment: Are you somewhat familiar with moment generating / characteristic functions?  I'd write it out using that approach, as it's simple, unless it's also unhelpful.

Comment: No I have not worked with moment generating functions. Do you have some idea of how to show that Poisson + some fixed probability of acceptance just scales the poisson rate? I am willing to learn the moment generating function approach based if you could show how this works out.

Comment: It'll be much later today (Pacific Std Time), I'm afraid; I can do it the straightforward way too, which will be less opaque.

Comment: I found some math showing how the distribution is still Poisson. But this seems to conflict in my mind with what I have "shown" using the negative binomial and the gamma distribution. Could you show me where I have gone wrong in that logic? I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: To repeat:  "If a single inter-arrival time can be calculated by sampling from a gamma based on N and R"... is wrong.  What you have done is calculated the total arrival time between the $0^{th}$ and the $N^{th}$ arrivals.  This does indeed have a Gamma dist'n with shape parameter $N$, but the interarrival time between any two consecutive arrivals is still exponential (also known as a Gamma dist'n with shape parameter = 1.)

Comment: But I think that it is not wrong, based on the output of my code. It's just that the shape parameter happens to also be a random variable. Somehow a gamma with a geometrically distributed shape parameter is equivalent to an exponential distribution. So while you are right about the distribution being exponential, sampling from a gamma distribution in the way I have done *does* sample the inter-arrival time of radiation events on the detector. It would be much simpler (but seemingly equivalent) to sample from an exponential(PR) though.

Comment: It cannot be that a gamma with a geometrically distributed shape parameter is equivalent to an exponential, as a gamma with a shape parameter = 1 is an exponential, and a geometric distribution doesn't equal a degenerate distribution with $p(x=1) = 1$.

Comment: You can run the code I posted in Matlab or Octave if you like and see. A gamma(N,R) where N is distributed as geom(P) looks pretty identical to exp(PR). The distribution of p(x=1) does not need to be 1 if the exponential has a higher mean parameter than the one used in the gamma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick non-technical argument might use [Jackson networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_network). In your case total external arrivals is rate $R$, and there are no internal transitions (observed particles don't switch to the unobserved queue). The splitting proportion between the observed and unobserved nodes $p_{0i}$ is $P$, so the

$\lambda_{obs}=RP$

If you're looking for first principles, call $O(t)$ the observed counting process, and $N(t)\sim PP(r)$ the total counting process. Where each arrival in $N(t)$ gets logged in $O(t)$ with probability $p$. So that if for some $s$ we have $N(s)=n$ then $O(s)$ has a binomial($n,p$) distribution.

This approach uses probability generating functions:

$E[z^{O(t)}|N(t)=n]=\sum_{j=0}^{n}z^{j} {n \choose j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}=(1-p+pz)^{n}$

Last equality by the binomial theorem. Then, unconditionally, since $N(t)\sim Poisson(rt)$:

$E[z^{O(t)}]=E[E[z^{O(t)}|N(t)=n]]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-p+pz)^{n}\frac{rt^n}{n!}e^{-rt}=e^{-rt}e^{rt(1-p+pz)}=e^{rpt(z-1)}$

Which is the probability generating function of a Poisson($rpt$) random variable.